# Installing python 2.7.1 on Solaris 10. Is compiling the only option?

Tags: python, installation, solaris-10

I'm new to installing anything on Solaris 10 on a sparc. For most of my linux/mac's it came pre-installed.
And installing on Windows is a breeze.

Now I have to install both Python & Mysql and seems like building it from source is the only option..

Here are my questions :
1.) Is compiling from source the only option ?!
2.) If I have to compile from source, what are the steps ? I think I'm a bit nervous doing this since I haven't done it.
3.) If number 2 is the only option, at what stage will I require root access ?

Comment: Just found this = http://sunfreeware.com/ I hope this will have the 2.7.1 for 10